# Elasticsearch update mapping without re-indexing the existing data

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, elasticsearch-indices

How to update the existing mapping to include eager-ordinals for a field. This has to be done without re-indexing the data is it possible ? We are using index template to apply mappings and settings to the index.

Problem with creating the new index is it always applies the mapping from index template. Is it possible to ignore index template for a particular index alone ?

Comment: Why don't you update the mapping in your template to make sure all future indices are correct?

Comment: I need to test mapping change with one index first thats why we are not changing the template. We are trying to test the search query performance by changing the global-ordinals to eager in one index. If the performance is good we will change the template itself.

Comment: There are [very few things](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html#updating-field-mappings) you can change in an existing mapping once it's been created, and adding `eager_global_ordinals` is not one of them unfortunately.

Comment: other than eager_global_ordinals is there any other option to improve the aggregation performance

Comment: hard to tell with so few information :-) all I can say is that performance tuning must be done **before** carving your mapping into the stone

Comment: thank you for your suggestion

Comment: @val what is the information needed to tell your suggestion to improve performance